# How to play an alarm for iPhone and iPad programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, alarm

How can I play an alarm for iPhone and iPad programmatically? What is the UI used for iPhone? Is there any sample reference for getting an idea?

Answer (score 4):

You need `UILocalNotification`.

You can find good tutorials about how to create a reminder [here](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/11/12/setting-a-reminder-using-uilocalnotification-in-ios-4-objective-c/) or [here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, If you did not understand my question properly.. You have to play alarm without settings time and date for suppose in a week we will get the week days of the month and play the alarm on selecting the days in specified day.. if you dont know question ask me. dont give negative ranking to question

Comment: Uh..? First, I didn't down vote your question. Second I understood you question as it was written and I answered it. You never mentioned what you said in your comment. My answer has been upvoted twice which means 2 people found that my answers was good and relevant to the question. Now, your question has been downvoted twice, which means that maybe you didn't give enough informations. What do you reckon ?

Comment: And I didn't understand your comment anyway... update your question

Answer (score 1):

This will help you more: [repeating an iOS local notification](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/9/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html).

It's a good tutorial for repeating Notifications. Here's a sample image:

[image: sample repeating notification]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Get sample [here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/).

Comment: The problem with LocalNotiication is you can't play a sound more than 30sec. You can't snooze is if user don't stop alarm, or you can't snooze without entering in app if you want to sleep for few more mins.

Comment: @KapilChoubisa This is the only way to achieve this I guess. Do you know anyother method?

Comment: Actually i want the same UI as that of Alarm in iPhone,simply i want to play alarm by using user given time and date,like snoozing and all

Comment: The answer is No,you cant. if you want snooze option, you should view the notification, then it will redirect to your application, there you should display "Snooze or OFF". For example, take a look at 2Do application.